# One time setting of value in Set /p

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file that copies pdf files in different server. 
The file name of the folder destination of files in desktop must be like this '2 Backup (name of user)'.

So, I want the user input their name once and make the inputted name the default value  of /p variable. (kinda like remember this when inputting password in a login form)

```
set /p name=Input your name:
```

so that when I xcopy files it would look like this :

```
xcopy "%setPath%\08_AUG\%day_month%\%code%\%code%sample.pdf" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\2 Backup %name%\%code%\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H
```

can someone help?

Comment: What is the problem, have you tried the command? Does the destination folder already exist?

Comment: there is no problem in my sample command it works, and the folder exist or not exist it will create a folder in desktop automatically. What I want is the user must be input their name once.. so that they don't have to enter their name each time they will open the batch file..

Comment: can you make the specific code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `set /p` with this snippet to set `name` locally ***and*** persistent.

```
if not defined name (
    set /p "name=Input name for 2 Backup:"
    call setx name "%%name%%"
)
```

Without knowing your batch [delayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) state using a pseudo call instead.